# Strongly and weakly polynomial time of linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

Wikipedia says that there is an open problem in linear pogramin which is:
"Does LP admit a strongly polynomial-time algorithm?"
There is also a definition of strongly and weakly polynomial time in Wikipedia but I did not realy understand it.
Can you explain me what is the difference between strongly and weakly polynomial time in the context of LP problem.

I undersdant it like this: strongly polynomial time means that I can get the **exact** solution in poly time, and weakly means that I can **approximate** the solution for every fixed epsilon-error. Am I right?
Thanks.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com